# Google Navigation Bar

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, navbar

I use Google navigation with navigation bar. My app use monoactivity where I set fragment at fragment container.
The question is how can I hide navigation bar when I go to another fragment?

Comment: please include enough code here for others to recreate and understand what you're talking about

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the toolbar at the top, from your fragment in the `onCreateView` you can call

```
(requireActivity() as <MonoActivity>).supportActionBar?.hide()
```

This should achieve that you want.